# Safely secure database connection string on an ubuntu server

Tags: php, .htaccess, connection

I have root access to the server, and I want to secure my php connection string to a database.

My files are located in `/var/www/html/`

Is it possible to put the connection PHP script in `/var/www/html/connect.php` and save the connection string elsewhere, like in `/home/`?

I've played with `.htaccess` as well, but not getting to far in my research.

Comment: As long as connect.php doesn't print anything, and your server is secure, it won't be exposed on the web.

Comment: it connects to the database and echos the query as JSON. I have still heard this way is not secure if php messes up you are doomed.

Comment: @JonathanAllen, simply keep your database connection file outside of the webroot in `/var/www/`, and then include that file. This is smart practice as there could be server related failures which could lead to displaying php source code (has happened to Facebook).

Comment: I have tried that, but it will not include for some reason. What is the proper format?